# Dask Distributed: Introduce graph dendencies on per worker initialisation tasks

Tags: python, dask

In dask distributed, tasks are distributed over a cluster nodes via scheduler. I'm looking to introduce a per node dependency on task submitted to a node. Briefly, a compute operation that I'm seeking to perform needs to:

1. Preload data onto a GPU on each node.
2. Perform GPU compute on each node with other data in chunked dask arrays.

I also want to enqueue (1) and (2) multiple times multiple times on differing datasets.

I've tried to set this up as a minimal example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import dask.array as da
from dask.base import tokenize
from distributed import (Client, LocalCluster,
                         get_worker, as_completed)
import numpy as np

cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=0)
cluster.start_worker(name="Alice")
cluster.start_worker(name="Bob")
cluster.start_worker(name="Eve")

with cluster, Client(cluster.scheduler_address) as client:
    workers = client.scheduler_info()['workers'].values()
    workers =  [v['name'] for v in workers]

    print("Workers {}".format(workers))

    def init_worker():
        get_worker()._stuff = 0
        return "OK"

    # Call init_worker on each worker. Need pure to
    # ensure this happens multiple times
    init_futures = [client.submit(init_worker, pure=False,
                                            workers=[w])
                                  for w in workers]

    assert all(f.result() == "OK" for f in as_completed(init_futures))

    A = da.arange(0, 20, chunks=(5,), dtype=np.float64)

    def inc_worker(A):
        w = get_worker()
        w._stuff += 1
        print("{}[{}]".format(w.name, w._stuff))
        return A + w._stuff

    def increment(A):
        """ Call inc_worker """
        from dask.base import tokenize
        name = 'increment-' + tokenize(A)
        dsk = { (name, i): (inc_worker, (A.name, i))
                        for n, i in A.dask.keys() }

        dsk.update(A.dask)
        return da.Array(dsk, name, A.chunks, A.dtype)

    print(increment(A).compute())
    print(increment(A).compute())
```

I want to find some way to make the `increment-*` tasks submitted to each worker dependent on the `init-worker-*` tasks submitted to each worker.
Put another way, I want avoid waiting for the `init_futures` to complete in the client. The problem this introduces is that, while we known which `init-worker-*` tasks are associated with each worker, there is no obvious way to know beforehand the worker association of the `increment-*` tasks.

One Possible Approach:

1. For each `inc_worker` call, spawn a `local_client()` that submits a task with the `init-worker-*` in `get_worker().data` as a dependency. I don't like this because the overhead seems quite large.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

**EDIT 1**: Actually this works without waiting for the `init_futures` to complete, presumably because they're submitted to the worker schedulers before any of the `increment-*` tasks are submitted to the worker. It still feels like I'm making an assumption that may not always be True though...

**EDIT 2**: Mentioned that the 2 steps should be run multiple times on different datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options:

1. Use `client.run` and wait.  This does what your submit trick above does, but more explicitly and with less pain.  It does however block, which you've said you don't want to do.

   ```
   client.run(init_worker)
   ```
2. Use a worker --preload script to run arbitrary code as a worker starts up.  See http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html?highlight=preload#customizing-initialization

   ```
   cluster.start_worker(..., preload=['myscript.py'])
   ```
3. Make `init_worker` idempotent (can be run many times without affect) and always call it within `inc_worker`

   ```
   def init_worker():
       if not hasattr(get_worker(), '_stuff'):
           get_worker()._stuff = 0

   def inc_worker(...):
       init_worker(...)
       ... do other things ...
   ```

Also, I notice that you're constructing dask.arrays by hand.  You might want to look at [x.map_blocks(my_func)](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.map_blocks) and `x.to_delayed/x.from_delayed`

Comment: I should've mentioned that I wanted to run steps (1) and (2) as a logically grouped operation many times. So I want to perform (A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, ..., Z1, Z2) in that order and where A, B, C, ..., Z are the logically grouped iterations.

Comment: What are your thoughts on option 3?  Idempotent setup functions are decently clean.  Perhaps you attach a new `dict` to the worker and have each of A, B, C, and D operate on a new key/value pair within that dict?

Comment: Yes, a `get_worker()._wait_tasks = {'A' : key1, 'B' : key2, 'C' : key3 ..., 'Z'  keyn }` is probably a good way to go.